# Logitech K350 keyboard and mouse freezes constantly on MacBook Pro with Monterey v 12.6.6

Tags: keyboard, mouse, driver

There are no Logitech drivers installed on my new MacBook. Is this the problem? I don't need to install anything on Windows or Linux and the K350 works beautifully on those systems.

When I try to download from [Logitech](https://logitechg502.com/logitech-k350-driver-and-software/) it downloads a Windows executable. If I need the Logitech drivers on macOS where can I get them from?

Comment: It should just work as a standard keyboard.  How are you connecting, Unifying Receiver or Bluetooth?  Can you test with a different computer to ensure there’s no problem with the keyboard and/or receiver (if applicable)?

Comment: Already tested on a different computer (Linux) where the keyboard and mouse work with no issues.  The connection is through a usb-c adapter where I plugin the Logitech bluetooth receiver to a usb port.

Comment: That’s actually not BT - it’s Logitech’s proprietary wireless tech.  Don’t try to pair it to your Mac (remove if you tried to do so).  Just plug it in to your Mac and go.

Comment: I didn't pair it to the macbook.  It's plugged into the usb-c adapter.  I've tried two usb-c adapters with the same bad results.

Comment: Try plugging into a proper hub and not an adapter.  It’s also not a Bluetooth Keyboard (just read the specs).

Comment: Its a usb type-c hub.  (The keyboard froze 4 times typing that first short sentence.)

Comment: Your link, btw, is not to Logitech but to some fake driver site. Keyboards don't need drivers, unless it's to enable customisation or special features. The most common cause of 'jumpiness' is interference. It looks like that is a 2.4GHz device which is a very crowded bit of airspace. See https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025340653-FAQ-Wireless-Keyboard-K350

Answer (score 0):

I switched to a corded keyboard and mouse and they work without any issues using the same usb-c hub.  The keyboard setup assistant didn't recognize the K350 keyboard but it did recognize the corded keyboard with the same key layout.

For some reason the Macbook Pro can't recognize the K350 keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It's quite unclear, what have you found finally?